# How can I identify specific strings in a dataframe and assign a new column to specific values?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics

Apologies if my question is a bit rubbish! - I'm quite new to R, and have never been great at coding.

Background: I have a dataframe of gene names and other values. I have a list of specific gene names which I want to label as of interest in a new column. I.e. column name: "OfInterest", with values either "Y" or "N".

**Here's what I've tried so far:**

```r
DataframeName <- import("filename.xlsx") %>%     
  as_tibble()

GenesOfInterest <- c('GeneA', 'GeneB', 'GeneC', etc...) 

DataframeName$OfInterest <- 'N'

DataframeName$OfInterest <- (if_else(DataframeName$GeneSymbol == GenesOfInterest, DataframeName$OfInterest <- 'Y', DataframeName$OfInterest <- 'N', NULL))
```

---

So basically... I'm trying to say that if any of the strings within my "GenesOfInterest" list are found within my column "GeneSymbol", the corresponding row should be filled in as "Y" in my "OfInterest" column.

I'm then gonna ggplot the data in to a volcano plot, wherein I'll have anything from the "OfInterest" column colour coded accordingly - But I think I should be okay with this part.

As it is, the code seems to find the very first string in my list (i.e. GeneA) and marks that as "Y" accordingly into the correct column, but stops after this first one, with warning message:

*Warning message:
In DataframeName$GeneSymbol == GenesOfInterest :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length*

Unfortunately, I don't understand what this means!

If anyone would be able to kindly offer help/suggestions, I'd be very thankful :) I feel like it is probably an easy fix, but I'm pretty inexperienced with R.

Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Would you be so kind and `dput()` your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
DataframeName$OfInterest[DataframeName$GeneSymbol %in% GenesOfInterest] <- 'Y'
DataframeName$OfInterest[DataframeName$OfInterest != 'Y'] <- 'N'
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
DataframeName %>%
      mutate(OfInterest = case_when(GeneSymbol %in% GenesOfInterest ~ 'Y', TRUE ~ 'N'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign the value in `ifelse`. Try this -

```
DataframeName$OfInterest <- ifelse(DataframeName$GeneSymbol %in% GenesOfInterest, 'Y', 'N')
```